# jQuery wrap on svg path hides the path

Tags: jquery, html, svg, anchor

I am trying to wrap a svg path into an HTML anchor element. The problem is, that the wrapping is done, but the svg path doesn't show up anymore at the page.

```
$('svg-path').each(function() {
    var li_name = $(this).data("name");
    $(this).wrap($('<a xlink:href=""></a>'));
    $(this).parent().attr("xlink:href", $(`.linker-${li_name}`).text());
  });
```

Hope somebody can help me out here.

Comment: Your jQuery selector seems wrong. What sort of element is named `<svg-path>`?  Is that a typo?  Did you mean `$('.svg-path')`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG `<a>` elements are different from HTML `<a>` elements.  They have a different namespace.  Your jQuery is inserting an HTML `<a>` element, which as far as the SVG render is concerned, is an invalid element. So it gets ignored, along with its contents (the `<path>`).

In general, you can't add SVG elements with jQuery. It is designed for HTML only. So you will need to use another method - such as vanilla JS.

```js
$('.svg-path').each(function() {
    var li_name = $(this).data("name");
    wrapSvgLink(this, li_name);
});


function wrapSvgLink(elem, url) {
  // Create an SVG <a> element
  var a = document.createElementNS(elem.namespaceURI, "a");
  // Add the xlink:href attribute
  a.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", url);
  // Insert the new <a> element into the DOM just before our path
  elem.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elem);
  // Move the path so it is a child of the <a> element
  a.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path class="svg-path" d="M 50,50 L 250,50 L 150,100 Z" data-name="foobar"/>
</svg>
```